# defining variables for methods in client jar

Tags: java, jax-ws, javadoc

I have a client jar from a piece of software that I develop, however when someone comes to use the client jar, they often find that the arguments for the method are undefined so they look like:

```
method(arg0, arg1, arg2,...)
```

This results in them having to look at the javadocs to see what they are meant to pass through. IS there anyway for updating the client so it looks nicer like:

```
method(String name, int age, String address,...)
```

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean that the problem is evident when they use the autocompletion function of their IDE. You need to tell us which IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Can you compile it with the debug symbols (the `-g` option)?

Comment: It's an ant script that I use to compile the client. Debug is on but my debug level may need tweaking  <javac srcdir="${SRC}" destdir="${BUILD}" nowarn="yes" source="1.6" target="1.6" includeAntRuntime="no" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">

Comment: No, I don't think changing debug level will help you, especially on a modern VM, and you have specified all of the options, so I don't have other ideas. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If this is when being used as a jar, then compile it with debug information.  For javac this is the `-g` flag.

If this is when accessed through a @WebService you must explicitly name each argument with @WebParam.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Examples_netbeans3.html for details.

Comment: All my @WebParam's are defined. It's an ant script that I use to compile the client. Debug is on but my debug level may need tweaking <javac srcdir="${SRC}" destdir="${BUILD}" nowarn="yes" source="1.6" target="1.6" includeAntRuntime="no" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">

Comment: Try removing the debugLevel argument.

Comment: No that didn't make a difference either

Comment: Where does the WSDL come from?